# Refresh Map after Invoke URL

Tags: spatial-database, layers, mapguide, autodesk

I am making a map on **Auto Desk Infrastructure Map Guide Studio**. Now I created a small ASP.NET website and hosted in local machine, Now on click of different buttons in flexible layout toolbar, I **invoke URL** for that asp.net page and it opens fine. I do some data querying on that page by selecting different options and execute query. The data changes in table in database and the effect is shown on the layer on map. Ok the issue is that I want to refresh the Auto desk map after invoke URL window is closed. And I want to do it by configuration in Map studio 2013. Does anyone have any idea how to refresh map automatically after **invoke URL? Or in other sense if the data in the data source of layer is changed.**

**Addtional Info:** the map always refresh when I click the refresh button from top or if I drag it or zoom it..Otherwise new layer data stays same.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a couple of things, either way, you'll have to dive in to JS a bit:

1) On the new window that was invoked, have a script that listens to the window's "onclose" event and in the function use window.opener to get to the map window. once you get the map window, get to your map object (http://www.mapguide.com/help/ver6/api/en/MGMap_intro.htm) and call refresh.

2) Use Invoke Script instead. Write a script that will get the selection and passes that to the same url in a new window. then watch for when that window closes, then call refresh on your map object.

3) Write your own widget that does the same as #2.

Good luck!